# Get list of custom web services

Tags: soap-api, webservices, custom, setup

Is it possible to get list of custom web services (SOAP API) from APEX classes ?
In Setup ->Develop->Apex Classes there are all classes and it is difficult to find only specific one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to prefix your webservice classes with with ws or some other prefix so you can sort the Apex Classes and find them.

If you want to get really fancy with it, you could develop a Visualforce page and controller that either queries ApexClass or calls the Tooling API, and parse the SymbolTables for any webservice classes.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf

Comment: And, you could make it a list view using that convention. Simply create a new list, filtered by the name.